# Apache Ant BINARY download is missing a BINARY file?

Tags: linux, ant, installation

Failing to simply copy a binary to linux machine.  Wow! I feel stupid today!  Below is the list of files in the binary package's tar.gz, as downloaded from default mirror and utah.edu:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 ec2-user ec2-user 10321 Apr  9  2016 ant
-rw-r--r-- 1 ec2-user ec2-user  7472 Apr  9  2016 ant.bat
-rw-r--r-- 1 ec2-user ec2-user  2857 Apr  9  2016 ant.cmd
-rw-r--r-- 1 ec2-user ec2-user  3410 Apr  9  2016 antenv.cmd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 ec2-user ec2-user   861 Apr  9  2016 antRun
-rw-r--r-- 1 ec2-user ec2-user  1536 Apr  9  2016 antRun.bat
-rwxr-xr-x 1 ec2-user ec2-user  2116 Apr  9  2016 antRun.pl
-rwxr-xr-x 1 ec2-user ec2-user  3473 Apr  9  2016 complete-ant-cmd.pl
-rw-r--r-- 1 ec2-user ec2-user  4315 Apr  9  2016 envset.cmd
-rw-r--r-- 1 ec2-user ec2-user  1116 Apr  9  2016 lcp.bat
-rwxr-xr-x 1 ec2-user ec2-user  4333 Apr  9  2016 runant.pl
-rwxr-xr-x 1 ec2-user ec2-user  3385 Apr  9  2016 runant.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 ec2-user ec2-user  1817 Apr  9  2016 runrc.cmd
```

Am I missing something?  All I see is a DIRECTORY named "ant".  Obviously this won't run as expected by supremely simple "[INSTALL](http://ant.apache.org/manual/index.html)" instructions (primarily written for benefit of Windows users, summarized): 
"-Add the bin directory to your path.
 -Set the ANT_HOME environment variable 
 -You can check the basic installation with opening a new shell and typing ant."

If I need to run one of these files to "Install" the binary maybe the instructions could mention it.  As it is this looks to me like (again) like developers high on 'dozes forgetting about the other OS.

Comment: I see a shell script called `ant` not a directory. OK, less flippant. The binary distribution contains a the shell script and a bunch of binary `jar`s. You actually *do* add the `bin` folder to your `PATH` and run`ant`. "install" means, extract the tarball wherever you want and set up the environment.

Comment: Just coming back to this.  Can't believe I didn't catch that.  I was being stupid.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I see a shell script called `ant` not a directory. OK, less flippant. The binary distribution contains a the shell script and a bunch of binary `jar`s. You actually *do* add the `bin` folder to your `PATH` and run`ant`. "install" means, extract the tarball wherever you want and set up the environment.
                    – Stefan Bodewig